# Modificar campo de una consulta con visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Trabajando con visual studio con asp con visual basic, uno puede trabajar con tablas de una base de datos y, revisando un programa que me pasaron, para que aprenda un poco más, me di cuenta que uno también puede tomar datos de una variable como si usara una consulta, me explico:

```
Dim Detalle As New Detalle(Me.DetalleLabel.Text)

Dim ItemDetalle = (From p In Detalle Where p.NumeroFila = CInt(Me.NumeroItemHiddenField.Value) And Select p).Single
```

DetalleLabel guarda la siguiente información:

```
<tr class="filafondo">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>10688</td>
    <td>BUDIN LA CUMBRE CHOC/AVELLANAS*250G</td>
    <td>UN </td>
    <td align="right">1,000</td>
    <td align="center">0</td>
    <td align="right">1.190,00</td>
    <td align="right">1.190,00</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1126</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>645554001488</td>
    <td>0,9029</td>
    <td>0,9029</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="filafondo">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10741</td>
    <td>CEBOLLA EN ESCAMAS 25 GR- PRMESANA</td>
    <td>UN </td>
    <td align="right">1,000</td>
    <td align="center">0</td>
    <td align="right">390,00</td>
    <td align="right">390,00</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>366</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>7796373113500</td>
    <td>0,3893</td>
    <td>0,3893</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="filafondo">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>10746</td>
    <td>CONDIMENTO PARA CARNES 20 GR-PARMESANA</td>
    <td>UN </td>
    <td align="right">1,000</td>
    <td align="center">0</td>
    <td align="right">390,00</td>
    <td align="right">390,00</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>366</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>7796373114002</td>
    <td>0,3024</td>
    <td>0,3024</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
```

Y esta es la clase con la que me imagino que trabaja:

```
Public Class Detalle
    Inherits List(Of FilaDetalle)

    Public Sub New(Tabla As String)
        'eliminacion de los atributos
        Tabla = Tabla.Replace(" align=""right""", "")
        Tabla = Tabla.Replace(" align=""left""", "")
        Tabla = Tabla.Replace(" align=""center""", "")
        Tabla = Tabla.Replace(vbCrLf, "")

        Tabla = Tabla.Replace("</td>", "")
        Tabla = Tabla.Replace("</tr>", "")


        Dim Filas As String() = Split(Tabla, "<tr class=""filafondo"" >")
        For Each Fila In Filas
            If Fila <> String.Empty Then

                Dim FilaDetalle As New FilaDetalle
                FilaDetalle.NumeroFila = CInt(Split(Fila, "<td>")(1))
                FilaDetalle.Codigo = CInt(Split(Fila, "<td>")(2))
                FilaDetalle.Nombre = Split(Fila, "<td>")(3)

                FilaDetalle.UM = Split(Fila, "<td>")(4)
                FilaDetalle.Cantidad = CDec(Split(Fila, "<td>")(5))
                FilaDetalle.Descuento = CInt(Split(Fila, "<td>")(6))


                FilaDetalle.Precio = CDec(Split(Fila, "<td>")(7))
                FilaDetalle.Total = CDec(Split(Fila, "<td>")(8))

                FilaDetalle.Cod_Doc = CInt(Split(Fila, "<td>")(9))
                FilaDetalle.Num_CorrelativoInterno = CInt(Split(Fila, "<td>")(10))
                FilaDetalle.Numero_Item = CInt(Split(Fila, "<td>")(11))

                FilaDetalle.Cod_Barra = Split(Fila, "<td>")(12)
                FilaDetalle.Mnt_CifUnitario = CDec(Split(Fila, "<td>")(13))
                FilaDetalle.Mnt_CifTotal = CDec(Split(Fila, "<td>")(14))

                Me.Add(FilaDetalle)
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
End Class


Public Class FilaDetalle
    Property NumeroFila As Integer
    Property Codigo As Integer
    Property Nombre As String

    Property UM As String
    Property Cantidad As Decimal
    Property Descuento As Integer
    Property Precio As Decimal
    Property Total As Decimal

    Property Cod_Doc As Integer
    Property Num_CorrelativoInterno As Integer
    Property LecturaItemAutomaticoB As Boolean
    Property Numero_Item As Integer

    Property Cod_Barra As String
    Property Mnt_CifUnitario As Decimal
    Property Mnt_CifTotal As Decimal

End Class
```

Podrían ser más dependiendo de los items que tenga, pero para el caso que sean 3.

Entonces, así como puedo seleccionar la fila de estos items con esa consulta, uno podría modificar un campo??.

Probé tratando de poner UPDATE pero no me lo tomó, es posible hacer esto o existe otra forma?

Lo pregunto porque sé como se hace por javascript, pero al ir metiendo items a esta variable me refresca la pantalla y pierdo el valor del campo que modifico.

Muchas Gracias

MODIFIQUÉ la Clase, me había equivocado

Comment: Encontré una clase al final del código, voy a modificar mi pregunta para agregarlo

Comment: Vale, no había leido correctamente. No estás trabajando con base de datos, sino que es un xml. Entonces, no entiendo exactamente que es lo que quieres actualizar, ya que el origen es un texto

Comment: No, No hay un UPDATE en linq. Linq es solo un lenguaje de consultas que podes usar contra distintos tipo de objetos que permiten ser IEnumerable. Pero para cambiar los valores, son objetos comunes y corrientes, o sea que tienen propiedades y se cambian como cualquier otro objeto.

Comment: pero cómo podría cambiar uno? Por ejemplo del primer item, modificar el sexto valor que sale con un 0

Comment: @gbianchi no sé cómo cambiar ese valor, las tecnologías que manejo para programar no van tan atras jajaja

Comment: Estas confundiendo tecnologias. Antes de tratar de entender como modificar una propiedad de una variable, te recomiendo leas todo sobre linq y entiendas que hace. Linq es solo como hacer un select a una coleccion de objetos...

Comment: @gbianchi es que si tuviera el tiempo estudiaría esto como tu me dices, pero por la pega no lo tengo, me pasaron el código y me dijeron "ve cómo arreglarlo para el miercoles", por eso recurro a la comunidad

Comment: ItemDetalle tiene un objeto del tipo de tu clase, para modificar cualquier propiedad solo tenes que hacer ItemDetalle.Propiedad = nuevovalor... por eso te digo que tenes que entender que pasa.

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi, en `ItemDetalle` tendrás un objeto de tipo FilaDetalle (aunque la consulta es incorrecta pero bueno). Para modificar cualquier campo, simplemente debes hacer `ItemDetalle.Nombre = "texto"` (para cambiar el nombre por ejemplo). Pero en ningun caso es un _update_, y no vas a poder reflejar ese campo en el textbox donde tienes los datos ya que no es una estructura muy standard (es simplemente html pegado ahi)

Comment: @Pikoh tenía claro que estaba preguntando mal ya que como dije, no sé como trabajar esos datos con visual basic. Y por la estructura, no tiene nada de standard como dices pero así trabajaron el código. Muchas Gracias por la ayuda